# Implement custom library browser / type hierarchy in an Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cnf, gf

I'm creating an Eclipse Plugin for development using the [Grammatical Framework (GF)](http://www.grammaticalframework.org/), and once of the major features I want to implement a custom "library browser" for searching the [GF Resource Grammar Library](http://www.grammaticalframework.org/lib/doc/synopsis.html) (which will internally involve parsing a lot of header files manually). It would basically behave a lot like Eclipse's Java Type Hierarchy view, with my own implementation behind the scenes.

My question is, do you think the **Common Navigator Framework (CNF)** what I should be looking at? It seems suitable for my UI needs, but I thought I might ask just in case there's some other option I've overlooked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the point of CNF is to make your tree-like view extensible: to allow several different bundles to provide items in the tree, actions on them, etc.

If the usual `TreeViewer` with a content and label provider is enough, there is no reason to go for CNF; if it isn't, do use CNF.